# Invariant subsheaves of descent

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am stuck in the following assertion in the proof of Theorem 1.3.7 in  Huybrechts and Lehn's ``The Geometry of Moduli Spaces of Sheaves'': let $K/k$ be a field extension such that $k$ is the fixed field under the action of $G=\operatorname{Aut}_k(K)$. Let $E$ be a pure sheaf on a projective variety over $k$. Then a subsheaf $N\subset  E\otimes K$ is of the form $N=N_k\otimes K$ for some  subsheaf $N_k\subset  E$ if and only if $N$ is invariant under the induced action of $G$ on $N$.

The only if part is clear. For the if part, I tried to show that $N$ is of the form $N^G\otimes_kK$, but it is not obvious to me. Is this related to the theory of descent or representation? I am grateful if someone can give me some advices and references.

Comment: Is $K/k$ not assumed Galois (i.e. algebraic)? It might be true with zero restrictions, but I’d have to think more. If $K/k$ is algebraic this should just fpqc descent since, roughly, $\mathrm{Spec}(K)\times_{\mathrm{Spec}(k)}\mathrm{Spec}(K)=\mathrm{Spec}(K)^{\mathrm{Aut}(K/k)}$. It seems conceivable that it can work in this generality though since this holds  when your projective variety is a point (e.g. see Prop 16.7 here: https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/AG16.pdf).

Comment: I think Prop 16.7 shows the general result as in Prop 16.8, where Milne treats the case of the ideal subsheaf of the structure sheaf.